# Julia: Create vector by using indices in another vector

Tags: julia

I'd like to create a vector which copies values from a vector by using the indices specified in another vector. An example is below:

```
vectorA=[50,90,100,7,22]
index_tograb=[3,4,1]
# resulting vector would take 3rd value of vectorA as the first element and so on
# vector_result=[100,7,1]
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get elements of a vector by a vector of indices:

```
vectorA=[50,90,100,7,22]
index_tograb=[3,4,1]

vectorA[index_tograb] # [100,7,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use `list comprehension` as following:

```
vectorA = [50, 90, 100, 7, 22]
index_tograb = [3, 4, 1]
vector_result = vectorA[index_tograb]
print(vector_result)

#Output is [100, 7, 1]
```

Comment: The listed output is incorrect. It looks like you are assuming 0-based indexing.

Comment: Yes output is wrong, I wanted to give general explanation. Corrected my approach